# Why only the logout button disappears after refresh even if the logged in user is stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my angular application, after successful login, the user data is stored in the local storage. So in order to implement the auto login feature, that is to not loss the data while reloading, I implemented the below function in `auth.service.ts`

```js
user = new Subject<User>();


// refresh and stays logged in
  autoLogin() {
    const userData: {
      email: string;
      id: string;
      _token: string;
      _tokenExpirationDate: string;
    } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') || '{}');
    if (!userData)
      return;
    const loadedUser = new User(userData.email, userData.id, userData._token, new Date(userData._tokenExpirationDate));
    if (loadedUser.token) {
      this.user.next(loadedUser);
      const expirationDuration  = new Date(userData._tokenExpirationDate).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
      this.autoLogout(expirationDuration);
    }
  }


private handleAuthentication(email: string, userId: string, token: string, expiresIn: number) {
      const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000);
      const user = new User(email, userId, token, expirationDate);
      this.user.next(user);
      //this.autoLogout(expiresIn * 1000);
      localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
  }
```

Now I have a navbar component, where my logout function is present. The code I tried is :

`nav-bar.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  isAuthenticated = false;

  private userSub!: Subscription;

  constructor(private authService : AuthService) { }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(u => {
      // this.isAuthenticated = !u ? true: false;
      this.isAuthenticated = !u ? false : true;
      console.log(this.isAuthenticated);
      //this.isAuthenticated = !!u;
      console.log(this.isAuthenticated);
    });
  }
```

and my html code for the logout button

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" (click)="onLogout()" *ngIf="isAuthenticated">Logout</button>
```

When I refresh the page, only the logout button disappears but every other details after login remains.

Before refresh:

[image: Before Refresh]

After refresh :

[image: After refresh]

Comment: You mean after refreshing page you are logout?

Comment: After refreshing, the data remains in the localstorage, and only the logout button disappers

Comment: Can you create https://stackblitz.com/ sample?

Comment: stackblitz might be difficult as there is some credentials i use in between

Comment: for credentials part just call a method that check simple condition and return true or false

Comment: Let me create one

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without full stackblitz repro, but my initial guess would be that your subscription in you nav-bar happens after that the `user` subject have already emitted the data.

To overcome this, I'd change it to a:

```
user = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
```

Replay subject keeps a buffer (with size defined in it's constructor) and upon new subscription will replay the emissions in the buffer (in this case - always last value).

This way, when you subscribe after the login has happened, it will pass the latest value to your component.